# Disable zsh "smart" autocompletion for gem command, but keep ordinary path completion

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I'm on a Mac running macOS 12.0.1 and trying to switch over from `bash` to `zsh`. When I'm trying to issue something like the following command:

```
gem install pg -v 1.2.3 -- --with-pg_config=/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin/pg_config
```

if I get as far as

```
gem install pg -v 1.2.3 -- --with-pg_config=
```

and hit `TAB`, I don't get completions; I just get what seems from the terminal window title to be some thrashing back and forth between `ruby` and `zsh`; after about three seconds (and three thrashes), I get my cursor back.

From a well-timed `ctrl-C` it appears to calling a shell function `_gem`, defined in `/usr/share/zsh/5.8/functions/_gem`.

I assume `zsh` is trying to do something clever here, but whatever it is, it isn't working, I don't need it, and I don't care just why it's not working in my particular use case or on this particular system (Homebrew, RVM, whatever). I just want ordinary file/directory completion.

Is there a way to disable this specific `zsh` function, without e.g. ripping it out of `/usr/share/zsh` (where it'll just get put back by the next OS update anyway, probably)?

Comment: It is running `gem list --remote -q --no-versions` to get available gems. That takes 2 seconds on my system which doesn't seem too bad. I've posted a patch to the _gem function so it knows to expect build options after `--` so the problem will go with the next release of zsh, see https://zsh.org/workers/49584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the “new” (1990s) completion system, i.e. that there's a call to `compinit` in your `.zshrc` (or in the zsh configuration framework if you're using one), you can override standard completions in two ways:

- You can override a completion function such as `_gem` (for all the commands that use it) by placing a function with the same name in a directory that comes first on `$fpath`. That directory must be present on `$fpath` before the call to `compinit`.
- You can call [`compdef`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-compdef) to override what `compinit` has set up. This needs to be done after the call to `compinit`.

So to just complete file names after `gem`, run this after the call `compinit`:

```
compdef _files gem
```

---

However, you don't need to go to such drastic measures. There are ways to do a file completion even when zsh thinks the context calls for something else.

The conceptually simplest, but not the most convenient way is to temporarily change the context. For example, type `;l` , complete the file name, then remove `;l` . Or <kbd>Home</kbd> `0` <kbd>End</kbd>, complete the file name, <kbd>Home</kbd> <kbd>Del</kbd> <kbd>End</kbd>.

You can bind [`_bash_complete-word`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fbash_005fcompletions) to a key binding ending with `/`, such as `^X/`. Then press `^X/` anywhere to complete a file name. In your case, that only works if you put a space after `--with-pg_config`, not an equal sign, since this widget not treat `=` as a separator.

You can perhaps take advantage of [`_most_recent_file`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fmost_005frecent_005ffile-_0028_005eXm_0029), bound to `^Xm` by default. This completes the most recent file name, regardless of the context. In your case, that only works if you put a space after `--with-pg_config`, not an equal sign, since this widget not treat `=` as a separator. For example: `--with-pg_config /o` `^Xm` `/h` `^Xm` `/o` `^Xm` `/*pq` `^Xm` …

You can [define](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-defining-widgets) your own [completion widget](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Widgets) to complete files and bind it to a key.

```
_complete_files () {
  if [[ $PREFIX == [-0-9A-Z_a-z]##=* ]]; then
    IPREFIX+=${PREFIX%%\=*}=
    PREFIX=${PREFIX#*=}
  fi
  _main_complete _files
}
zle -C _complete_files complete-word _complete_files
bindkey '\e^F' _complete_files
```

Then you can press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F</kbd> anywhere to complete a file name. This function completes the current shell word, regardless of the context, except it ignores a prefix like `--option=`.